# User Groups and organization in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have a journal article and a document . I want to add a view permissions to both journal article and document to a organization and usergroup.I want it programatically using LIFERAY API.

Can anybody come with the solution??

Comment: Why do you want to add it programatically instead of adding permissions through Liferay's Admin port ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [liferay services](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/accessing-liferay-services) They allow you to modify about anything.
They can even be [triggered from the gui](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/running-scripts-from-the-control-panel) with a little coding (caution though as there is no undo).
Note that you may need authentication/athorization to run the services, alternatively the xxxxxserviceutil (e.g. JournalArticleServiceUtil) can be used from within hook/portlet code as root)

Good Luck!